# Python - Get timing property from network response

Tags: python, request

How to get the properties as shown on the image (Blocked, DNS resolution, Connecting ...) after sending the request?

From firefox, the waiting time = ~650ms

From python, `requests.Response.elapsed.total_seconds()` = ~750ms

Since the result is difference, i want to have a more details result as shown on firefox developer mode.

[image: ][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get the total time of the request because the response doesn´t know more itself.
More informations are only logged by the programms which does handle the request and start-stopping a timer for some steps.

You need to track times in/on you connection-framework or you can have a look on the FireFox [API for "timings"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) - there are some more APIs so maybe you find something you are able to use for your case - but main fact is you can´t do it directly and only with your script because request and response are fired/catched and logging/getting data does happen between other components then.

Comment: Thanks! But how does firefox works? May be i can through "firefox api" or some library to get those on python?

Comment: @onon99buynoodle check updated answer - it´s now complete. Have a nice day.